# Dynamically Call HTML File Using a Variable or JavaScript to give search results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search-engine

Have been having trouble finding how to dynamically call in an HTML file with jquery and javascript here is what I have (getContent is called when enter is pressed):

```
function getContent(){
    var inputval= $(input).val();
    document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="'inputvalue'.html" ></object>';
}
```

**Two things**

1. How could I fix the code above to work with a variable as the html files name and have it be the input's val();
2. **If there more effiecient way to call results through an input where data is in external files using javascript (AJAX or PHP are fine) it would be much appreciated**

By the way I am a bit of a javascript noob in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get($('input').val() + '.html', function (response) {
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML=response;
});
```

Comment: It gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null @NicolásStraubValdivieso

Comment: it's telling you there is no element with a `wrapper` id.